# Как установить cg_group на версию v1

Tags: ubuntu, package, install, armbian-linux

Мне необходима версия docker cg_group v1 но в интернете так и не нашел вариантов по ее установке. Подскажите как решить, может кто то уже сталкивался?

Вот ответ на вопрос какая версия:

```
asus:# stat -fc %T /sys/fs/cgroup/
cgroup2fs
```

Comment: Я не то чтобы сильно шарю в "дешёвой" виртуализации, но мне всё равно интересно зачем тебе старый кусок одной из систем.

Comment: Необходим для home assistant

Comment: Не оно? https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/runmetrics/#changing-cgroup-version